# How to make an <ul> act as an <ol> (with numbers instead of bullets)?

Tags: jquery, html, css, kendo-ui, kendo-panelbar

This is an unfortunate question, but I don't see any other way around it.

Basically, I am using Kendo UI panelbar to create expandable lists. The problem is, when you use an `<ol>` as the sublist, the panelbar functionality doesn't work.

**Example in Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/b3y62uzr/2/

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="panelBar1">
    <li>
        Item 1
            <ul>
                <li>Sub Item 1</li>
                <li>Sub Item 2</li>
            </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item 2
            <ol>
                <li>Sub Item 1</li>
                <li>Sub Item 2</li>
            </ol>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You can see that the first item can be expanded/collapsed properly, but the second item is always open and can't be interacted with.

In my application, **I need the sub-list in my expanded section to be numbered** rather than *bulleted*. (I modified the Kendo Panelbar styling to show the bullets).

**So the question is:** Is it possible to make an `<ul>` use numbers instead of bullets?

**Edit:** Use this Fiddle if you want for your answer: https://jsfiddle.net/1h2kLqu4/1/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes it is, you can use the `list-style-type` CSS property on the unordered lists.

You would target it like this:

```
ul li{
    list-style-type: decimal;
}
```

[Here is a fiddle showing you the result.](https://jsfiddle.net/pvxy3eym/)

Comment: Well that was surprisingly simple - can't believe I couldn't easily find that. Thanks!

Comment: No worries man, we've all bee there. Just yesterday I missed a period in a jQuery selector that gave me fits.